# Understanding Passport, Failed Serialization, 401 Error

Tags: javascript, express, authentication, jwt, passport.js

I have been tinkering with passport-jwt today, trying to figure out how to properly set it up in my application. I have had no issues registering a user and saving a jwt token but I don't think I was using passport to do so. Now I am trying to login in a user and I always receive the error `Error: Failed to serialize user into session`. I have seen in a number of articles the below:

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
      done(err, user);
  });
});
```

But I can't seem to find any examples or even the configure portion of the passport docs that explain where to use these. It could be the source of my issues but I am not certain. One of the aspects of Passport that I find confusing are the JWT extractors. Why would I ever need any of them (even though they are required) if all I want to do is turn my passport into a jwt token and save it in my mongo database? Wouldn't it be easier to just use `jsonwebtoken` myself and hash/unhash the string as needed and use `cookie-parser` to create my own session instead of using something like Passport? I have also attempted to use passport.authenicate() in my rest calls but those return 401's. You can see the failed attempt commented out below the login call.

Please help, I feel like I am the only one that is finding passport more complicated than something far less robust but I am really committed to sorting it out!

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import connection from './database';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import cors from 'cors';
import crypto from 'crypto';
import passport from "passport";
import passportJWT from "passport-jwt";
const JwtStrategy = passportJWT.Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = passportJWT.ExtractJwt;
import { User } from './schema';
import { read } from 'fs';
const app = express();
const corsOptions = {
  origin: '*',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

const jwtOptions = {
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromBodyField('Password'),
  secretOrKey: 'secretKey',
  jsonWebTokenOptions: { expiresIn: 172800 }
}

passport.use(new JwtStrategy(jwtOptions, (jwt_payload, done) => {
  User.findOne({ password: jwt_payload.sub }, (err, user) => {
    user ? done(null, user) : done(null, false);
  });
}));

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
      done(err, user);
  });
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Success');
  console.log(req.body);
  res.json(req.body);
});

app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.FirstName
    && req.body.LastName
    && req.body.Email
    && req.body.Password
  ) {
    const token = await jwt.sign(
      { Password: req.body.Password },
      jwtOptions.secretOrKey,
      { expiresIn: '48h' }
    );
    const CreatedAt = await Date.now();
    const newUser = await new User({
      FirstName: req.body.FirstName,
      LastName: req.body.LastName,
      Email: req.body.Email,
      Password: token,

    });
    await newUser.save(err => {
      err ? console.log(err) : res.json(newUser);
    });
  }
  throw new('error');
});

// app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
//   (req, res) => {
//     console.log(req.user)
//   if (req.body.Email && req.body.Password) {
//     User.findOne({ Email: req.body.Email }, (err, user) => {
//       if (err) return console.log(err);
//       console.log(user);
//       return user;
//     }).then((res) => {
//       jwt.verify(res.Password, jwtOptions.secretOrKey, (err, decoded) => {
//         err ? console.log(err) :
//         req.login(decoded, (err) => {
//           // if (err) { return next(err); };
//           if (err) {
//             console.log(err) 
//           } else {
//             console.log(decoded)
//           }
//         });
//       });
//     }).catch(err => console.log('Failed ', err));
//   } else {
//     console.log(req.body);
//   }
// });

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.Email && req.body.Password) {
    User.findOne({ Email: req.body.Email }, (err, user) => {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      console.log(user);
      return user;
    }).then((res) => {
      // res.password returns the jwt string successfully
      jwt.verify(res.Password, jwtOptions.secretOrKey, (err, decoded) => {
        err ? console.log(err) :
        req.login(decoded, (err) => {
          // if (err) { return next(err); };
          if (err) {
            console.log(err) // always returns the error posted above
          } else {
            console.log(decoded)
          }
        });
      });
    }).catch(err => console.log('Failed ', err));
  } else {
    console.log(req.body);
  }
});

app.listen(9000, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port 9000`);
});
```

Custom Extractor Attempt

```
    const customExtractor = req => {
  User.findOne({ Email: req.body.Email }, '_id', (err, user) => {
    const token = jwt.sign(
      { id: user },
      'secretKey',
      { expiresIn: '48h' }
    );
    return token;
  });
```

Based on the post by @OrthoHomeDefense I created the following and successfully sent a jwt token to the client:

```
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.Email && req.body.Password) {
    User.findOne({ Email: req.body.Email }, (err, user) => {
      if(user.Password === req.body.Password) {
        console.log()
        var token = jwt.sign(JSON.stringify(user), jwtOptions.secretOrKey);
        res.json({token: token});
      } else {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(401).json({message:"Passwords did not match."});
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.status(401).json({message:"Please provide an email and a password."});
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://jonathanmh.com/express-passport-json-web-token-jwt-authentication-beginners/

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense 
I have read through it before and it looks like I am stuck on The Passport JWT Strategy section since I am receiving a 401. The part I do not understand is the extractors themselves. Why would I receive jwt from any of the prescribed extractor locations? Isn't a jwt the hashed string that was once the provided password? In that case, aren't I receiving the jwt from the database, not any of the extractor locations? I know what I said must be wrong but I just can't seem to figure out how?

Comment: Can you show me what it looks like when you call the request on the client side?

Comment: POST http://localhost:9000/login 401 (Unauthorized)
index.js:13 Error: Request failed with status code 401
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:77)

Comment: What does your 'bearer' header look like?

Comment: I honestly can't find it and lost hope with that version after reading this https://github.com/themikenicholson/passport-jwt/issues/127 . But their version didn't help either, I have never seen an 'authorization' option in the header before. I tried to make my own custom extractor too with session cookies and a jwt-sign but all lead to 401.

Comment: See that is where I am fundamentally lost, where is the token? Is it a hashed password that I stored in the database? Most examples show an id that is associated with the token? Is that then stored in the database as a separate value? Or is it saved in a cookie? Do I need to manually set it in a header/body etc. when I make the request? How can I do that? if the token is saved in the db? Is that what the strategy is for? Is jwt_payload in jwtStrategy essentially req? So the db call in the strat should search based on id an return the token save in the _id?

Comment: I am so sorry for that response, I went on a thought tangent.

Comment: Sorry I mean after you login the 'jsonwebtoken' creates the token. In your code it's the package `import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';`

Comment: I can't really go through the docs yet but I will try to come up with a solution for you if I have the time.

Answer (score 1):

First off, @OrthoHomeDefense solved my initial issue regarding setting up the login as I was confused as for what needed to be followed to initial set it up and where to use passport.

The below is my call from the client to the server.

```
export const test = token => {
  console.log(token)
  return dispatch => {
    axios.post('http://localhost:9000/test',
    {
      headers: {'authorization': token},
      data: {test: 'test', Token: token}
    }
  ).then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
  }
}
```

Next is what relevant test I made on the server side.

```
const customExtractor = req => {
  let token = req.body.headers.authorization;
  console.log(token);
  return token;
}

const jwtOptions = {
  jwtFromRequest: customExtractor,
  secretOrKey: 'secretKey',
}

passport.use(new JwtStrategy(jwtOptions, (jwt_payload, done) => {
  console.log('Success', jwt_payload);
  User.findOne({id: jwt_payload.sub}, (err, user) => {
    if (err) return done(err, false);
    if (user) {
      return done(null, user);
    } else {
      return done(null, false);
    }
  });
}));
```

I tried the below extractors only to received a 404 every time so I created the very simple extractor above. If you save your token in a cookie or something similar then follow edit as applicable in your own extractor as I found it much easier to do it yourself.

`jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromBodyField('Token'),
jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromHeader("authorization"),`

Comment: Glad you found a solution

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `jwt.verify(...)` That is to verify a token. You don't need to verify a token on login do you? You need to create one on login.

step through this as your `/login` and tell me how it runs.

```
 app.post("/login", function(req, res) {
      if(req.body.name && req.body.password){
        var name = req.body.name;
        var password = req.body.password;
      }
      // usually this would be a database call:
      //find user by username and password
      if( !user ){
        res.status(401).json({message:"no such user found"});
      }

      if(verify user is correct) {

        //token is created here
        var token = jwt.sign(payload, jwtOptions.secretOrKey);
        //here is the response
        res.json({message: "ok", token: token});
      } else {
        error
        res.status(401).json({message:"passwords did not match"});
      }
    });
```

Comment: I posted my new code at the bottom of my question as it pertained to your above solution for login. If I am to understand this correctly, with every call to the server, I will need to send the provided jwt token to the server whenever `passport.authenticate()` is used like so `headers: {'Authorization': jwtToken},`? I assume saving the token in state is not very secure but I need to keep it somewhere when I am not making a call?

Comment: Yes that sounds about right. Where you store it depends on when the token expires and on the needs of the app. You could store it in a DB I don't see a problem with that. I haven't checked out the docs for passport thoroughly, but maybe they can do some of those steps for you. Let me know how it works out.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do not have any issues using the jwt token but unfortunately, if I use `app.post('/test', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), (req, res) => {console.log(req.body}` I still receive a 401. `axios.post('http://localhost:9000/login', { headers: {'authorization': token}, data: {test: 'test', Token: token} }` for what I send to the server. Tried extractors `fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken() fromHeader("authorization") fromBodyField('Token')` and none of them make a difference. I understand you aren't looking at the docs but good to know regardless.